# Benefit of keeping user interface state in a Redux store?

Tags: typescript, redux, ngrx, ngxs, akita

The NGRX [official demo application](https://stackblitz.com/github/ngrx/platform/tree/61cbfe537f9df8cef3dd4a6ee0b8f483e49653f4) keeps layout state in the store.

This [Akita Article](https://engineering.datorama.com/i-built-the-ngrx-demo-app-with-akita-heres-the-result-57f83fe92192) also keeps state like `searchTerm` etc in the Akita `EntityStore<Book>`.

Just curious whether there there are additional benefits to keeping user interface state in the store, instead of only in UI components?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [Redux FAQ entry on how to split state between the store and components](https://redux.js.org/faq/organizingstate#do-i-have-to-put-all-my-state-into-redux-should-i-ever-use-reacts-setstate):

> There is no “right” answer for this. Some users prefer to keep every single piece of data in Redux, to maintain a fully serializable and controlled version of their application at all times. Others prefer to keep non-critical or UI state, such as “is this dropdown currently open”, inside a component's internal state.
>
> ***Using local component state is fine***.  As a developer, it is *your* job to determine what kinds of state make up your application, and where each piece of state should live.  Find a balance that works for you, and go with it.
>
> Some common rules of thumb for determining what kind of data should be put into Redux:
>
> - Do other parts of the application care about this data?
> - Do you need to be able to create further derived data based on this original data?
> - Is the same data being used to drive multiple components?
> - Is there value to you in being able to restore this state to a given point in time (ie, time travel debugging)?
> - Do you want to cache the data (ie, use what's in state if it's already there instead of re-requesting it)?

Answer (score 2):

One thing to consider is when you use component state and a component is unmounted and remounted again, it's state is generally lost. If the component stores all of it's state in redux, then it's state can be kept.

This is often a factor when I use react-router in conjunction with redux. Some pages I want to navigate away from and return to them in the same state.